# How to run an R program in asp.net

Tags: r, asp.net-mvc, r.net

I am new to R.Net. I want to make a sample application that reads an Rcode and executes it to show the results to the user. Can anyone please suggest me some good tutorials to learn R.Net?

Comment: This question is off-topic in SO. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

These are good resources for Learning R.NET

1. https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238409.aspx
3. https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/
4. http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/
5. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/rtvs/

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following pages for the R.Net Tutorials

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/

https://www.rstudio.com/online-learning/

https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/